# How do I resample an irregular timeseries dataframe in pandas by grabbing nearest without interpolating

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I can't seem to find this anywhere, so apologies if it's a duplicate. I have some large datasets that have irregular timeseries.  I'd like to subsample them to **no more frequent** than every x minutes grouped by specific id, but keep the original timestamp.  The dataset looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [101,101,101,101,106,106,106],
                            'ti': [pd.Timestamp('2020-04-02T09:56:46'),
                                 pd.Timestamp('2020-04-02T10:17:01'),
                                 pd.Timestamp('2020-04-02T10:21:02'),
                                 pd.Timestamp('2020-04-02T10:37:09'),
                                 pd.Timestamp('2020-04-02T09:56:03'),
                                 pd.Timestamp('2020-04-02T09:59:34'),
                                 pd.Timestamp('2020-04-02T10:10:20')],
                           'lat': [-36.006335, -36.004282, -36.003927,
                                   -36.002455,-36.211260,-36.213578,
                                   -36.216875]})
```

Ideally, I'd have something like this for every 15 minutes, for example:

```
dfs = df.set_index('ti').groupby('id').resample('15T').nearest()

id        ti                  lat               
101  2020-04-02 09:56:46  -36.006335    
101  2020-04-02 10:17:01  -36.004282    
101  2020-04-02 10:37:09  -36.002455    
106  2020-04-02 09:56:03  -36.211260     
106  2020-04-02 10:10:20  -36.216875
```

but what I really get is this:

```
                          id        lat
id  ti                                 
101 2020-04-02 09:45:00  101 -36.006335
    2020-04-02 10:00:00  101 -36.006335
    2020-04-02 10:15:00  101 -36.004282
    2020-04-02 10:30:00  101 -36.002455
106 2020-04-02 09:45:00  106 -36.211260
    2020-04-02 10:00:00  106 -36.213578
```

If I use '15m', it's only keeping the first timestamp of each id.

I also imagine there's a way to group by id, get minimum/maximum time, calculate the number of points that would exist if they were theoretically at ~x minute intervals and subsample based on that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Everyone who's trying to help you will first have to tediously build a sample dataframe that you failed to provide. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And I don't see how your 'ideal' result has a frequency of 15 min. I guess as soon as you're able to properly formulate your question you'll also be able to solve it yourself.

Comment: It needs to have a frequency of no greater than 15 minutes.  I simply need to subsample a semi-random time series so it removes points that're closer together than 15 minutes - ideally without iterating.  I'm not clear on what the .nearest() is doing.  This is only the second question I've posted.  I'll add a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This gets close:

```
df.sort_values(by=['id','ti'], inplace=True, ascending=True)

#Make redundant timestamp to use later
df['t0'] = df['ti']
#Get closest points to 15 minute time series
dfs = df.set_index('ti').groupby('id').resample('15T').nearest()

#Fix Indices
dfs = dfs.reset_index(level=['ti'])
dfs = dfs.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=False)

#Find values closest to 15 minute interval and remove others duplicates
dfs['tf'] = abs(dfs.t0-dfs.ti).astype('timedelta64[m]')
dfs = dfs.sort_values('tf').drop_duplicates(subset=['id','t0'], keep='first')

dfs = dfs.sort_index()
```